# Column ambiguously defined even though I used aliases / odbc ignores aliases

Tags: odbc, hana

I am using SAP HANA database and this is my query, run from php file.

```
SELECT 
    T0."DocNum", T0."createDate",
    T0."resolution",
    T0."description"    
FROM  
    T.PDVQ T0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T.POYN T1 ON T1."It" = T0."i"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T.PDVD T2 ON T2."stat" = T0."status" 
LEFT JOIN 
    T.PIDT T3 ON T0."assignee" = T3.USER
LEFT JOIN 
    T.PJRQ T4 ON T0."tech" = T4."empID"
ORDER BY 
    T0."DocNum" DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I can see the values under column T0."createDate" but not T0."resolution" and T0."description".

Besides I am getting this error:

> odbc_result(): SQL error: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;268 column ambiguously defined: createDate

If I delete `T0."createDate"` from query, I can see the values under T0."resolution" and T0."description" without any error.

What could be the reason for that? I need all in the same query, how do i fix it?

Both `T1` and `T0` has `createDate`
T0."DocNum" didn't make any difference

odbc functions I used

```
$view=odbc_exec($conn,$query);   
while(odbc_fetch_row($view)) 
{ 
    for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($view);$i++) 
    { 
    echo odbc_result($view,$i);
    } 
}
```

**Edit 2:** According to my observations query is working on SAP itself. It seems like odbc ignores the aliases. But why I can get `T0."createDate"` when I delete  `T0."resolution"`,
`T0."description"` from query?

Comment: No table alias is specified for `"DocNum"` column. Try to specify.

Comment: @Serg unfortunately nothing's changed

Comment: Could you try `T0."createDate" AS "CreateDate"`?

Comment: @gotqn didn't work...

Comment: Could you try change the alias `T0` to something else

Comment: @pbooksdgy you are not getting any data from the T1,T2,T3 and T4 tables - could you remove them?

Comment: @gotqn actually, I will but removed them to give it a try, nothing's changed

Comment: So, could you remove them and show what's left and again causing the error?

Comment: @SelVazi it is saying invalid identifier, I don't understand why

Comment: @pbooksdgy this is strange - if you perform SELECT * FROM this table, could you see the error again?

Comment: Yes and also for another columns which I don't need. @gotqn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252900/discussion-between-gotqn-and-pbooksdgy).

Comment: Feedback from the chat: OP says it works well `SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."createDate", T0."resolution", T0."description" FROM T.PDVQ T0 ORDER BY "DocNum" DESC LIMIT 10`, so @gotqn says "it seems your issue was that "DocNum" it's not reffer with the table alias in your original query, add T0. too".

Comment: @SandraRossi doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments, if the following code returns the error `odbc_result(): SQL error: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;268 column ambiguously defined: createDate`, it means that either you have a big trouble with your HANA software (whatever it is HANA Studio or HANA database system) and you should reinstall.

```
SELECT 
    T0."DocNum", T0."createDate",
    T0."resolution",
    T0."description"    
FROM  
    T.PDVQ T0 
ORDER BY 
    T0."DocNum" DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

**Pay attention to using the table name or alias (`T0` in the query above) at **all places** where "DocNum" is indicated** as per the SAP note [2695943 - SQL failed with error "column ambiguously defined"](https://me.sap.com/notes/0002695943):

> "*[When executing via HANA studio SQL console or hdbsql] When columns are used, table name needs to be defined, otherwise, error message "column ambiguously defined" will occur...*"
>
> "*If your SQL statement contains column_name, for example `ORDER BY "<column_name>"` And the execution failed with error "column ambiguously defined", you need to modify the statement to include the table name, for example `ORDER BY <table_name>."<column_name>"*"

It's also a big problem as this query returns the error `invalid column name error` whatever you indicate for 'MY_TABLE':

```
SELECT T.COLUMN_NAME, T.DATA_TYPE_NAME
FROM SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS T
WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

(reference: [TABLE_COLUMNS System View](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=TABLE_COLUMNS%20System%20View&product=SAP_HANA_PLATFORM))

Comment: I made it work the last query. It is not giving error anymore. Thanks for the answer. I really don't know how to fix this. Actually, I realized this query is working inside HANA database and I am running  this query from a php file. Maybe it is something about ODBC or php or anything about my syntax....

Comment: It's important to ask questions with full explanation/context how you do it ([minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that people can reproduce and answer precisely.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that before asking. @sandra rossi

Comment: You can think about it after asking, and complete your question. In your question, you have said "there is nothing wrong with the query since it is working on SAP itself", you're wrong because SQL is not a universal thing, each software may interpret it differently.

Comment: I meant in terms of table relations but I see your point ,I'll edit the question @Sandra Rossi.