# Select multiple columns from multiple tables without union

Tags: hana

For some reason I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897674/column-ambiguously-defined-even-though-i-used-aliases) problem. To sum up, I can't get some specific values together. I need to get value of T0."createDate" so I think there might be a way to select that value from T0 using separate SELECT.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT("DocNum") FROM TT) AS TOTAL FROM TT;
```

But of course it won't work because I select more than one columns.

This is basically what I want to do:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT TOP 1 "DocNum",
    T0."resolution",
    T0."description"  FROM T.PDVQ T0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T.POYN T1 ON T1."It" = T0."i"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T.PDVD T2 ON T2."stat" = T0."status" 
LEFT JOIN 
    T.PIDT T3 ON T0."assignee" = T3.USER
LEFT JOIN 
    T.PJRQ T4 ON T0."tech" = T4."empID") AS DATEX,(SELECT T0."createDate" FROM T.PDVQ T0 ) AS OTHERS FROM TT; --I don't know about this TT
```

Can't use UNION because

> LOB type column is not allowed in set

Comment: Can you do `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @jarlh I got this error: `inconsistent datatype: mismatched column types in set`

Comment: Hi - please update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve. BTW all questions should be self-contained - so while linking to other question may provide additional information, it should not be required that someone goes and reads that question in order to understand this question

Comment: Actually it is not needed to understand the question, just for the reason why @NickW